# Drupal website in sub folder not loading images

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I am new with drupal and stuck at one place.
Uploaded the website in subfolder, So the website path looks like

www.example.com/website/

the website works but images in website dont
as the src in images is like

/sites/default/themes/livinmin/images/fb-icon.png

Due to this its taking / 2 times and did not able to load the images.

Comment: permission of the image must not be correct, set it to 777 and then check it

Comment: it works fine when moving it from subfolder to main folder.. i just have issue with subfolder path

Comment: > Due to this its taking / 2 times and did not able to load the images.

I'm not sure what this means? are you meaning that the URL is coming out as http://www.example.com/website//sites/default/themes/livinmin/images/fb-icon.png It's interesting to me that setting the `$base_url` didn't work for you. Do you have anything set in your vhost file?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Parameter called `$base_url` in `sites/default/settings.php` that you can set to, say `http://www.example.com/website` that Drupal should use for generating your links correctly.